# Kubernetes monitoring service heapster keeps restarting

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service, heapster

I am running a kubernetes cluster using azure's container engine. I have an issue with one of the kubernetes services, the one that does resource monitoring `heapster`. The pod is relaunched every minute or something like that. I have tried removing the heapster deployment, replicaset and pods, and recreate the deployment. It goes back the the same behaviour instantly.

When I look at the resources with the heapster label it looks a little bit weird:

```
$ kubectl get deploy,rs,po -l k8s-app=heapster --namespace=kube-system
NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/heapster   1         1         1            1           17h

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/heapster-2708163903   1         1         1         17h
rs/heapster-867061013    0         0         0         17h

NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/heapster-2708163903-vvs1d   2/2       Running   0          0s
```

For some reason there is two replica sets. The one called `rs/heapster-867061013` keeps reappearing even when I delete all of the resources and redeploy them. The above also shows that the pod just started, and this is the issue it keeps getting created then it runs for some seconds and a new one is created. I am new to running kubernetes so I am unsure which logfiles are relevant to this issue.

**Logs from heapster container**

```
heapster.go:72] /heapster source=kubernetes.summary_api:""
heapster.go:73] Heapster version v1.3.0
configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://10.0.0.1:443" and version v1
configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10255
heapster.go:196] Starting with Metric Sink
heapster.go:106] Starting heapster on port 8082
```

**Logs from heapster-nanny container**

```
pod_nanny.go:56] Invoked by [/pod_nanny --cpu=80m --extra-cpu=0.5m --memory=140Mi --extra-memory=4Mi --threshold=5 --deployment=heapster --container=heapster --poll-period=300000 --estimator=exponential]
pod_nanny.go:68] Watching namespace: kube-system, pod: heapster-2708163903-mqlsq, container: heapster.
pod_nanny.go:69] cpu: 80m, extra_cpu: 0.5m, memory: 140Mi, extra_memory: 4Mi, storage: MISSING, extra_storage: 0Gi
pod_nanny.go:110] Resources: [{Base:{i:{value:80 scale:-3} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:80m Format:DecimalSI} ExtraPerNode:{i:{value:5 scale:-4} d:{Dec:<nil>} s: Format:DecimalSI} Name:cpu} {Base:{i:{value:146800640 scale:0} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:140Mi Format:BinarySI} ExtraPerNode:{i:{value:4194304 scale:0} d:{Dec:<nil>} s:4Mi Format:BinarySI} Name:memory}]
```

Comment: What do the logs of the heapster pod say? Does it exit due to some error? Also which [restartPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) is set for that pod?

Comment: @fishi I have added logs to the question

Comment: The pod had restartPolicy Always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it happens to be a problem in the azure container service default kubernetes configuration. I got some help from an azure supporter.

The problem is fixed by adding the label `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists` to the heapster deployment. Here is the pull request that the supporter referenced: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pull/1133

Answer (score 1):

It is completely normal and important that the Deployment Controller keeps old ReplicaSet resources in order to do fast rollbacks.

A Deployment resource manages ReplicaSet resources. Your heapster Deployment is configured to run 1 pod - this means it will always try to create one ReplicaSet with 1 pod. In case you make an update to the Deployment (say, a new heapster version), then the Deployment resource creates a new ReplicaSet which will schedule a pod with the new version. At the same time, the old ReplicaSet resource sets its desired pods to 0, but the resource itself is still kept for easy rollbacks. As you can see, the old ReplicaSet `rs/heapster-867061013` has 0 pods running. In case you make a rollback, the Deployment `deploy/heapster` will increase the number of pods in `rs/heapster-867061013` to 1 and decrease the number in `rs/heapster-2708163903` back to 0. You should also checkout the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) about the Deployment Controller (in case you haven't done it yet).

Still, it seems odd to me why your newly created Deployment Controller would instantly create 2 ReplicaSets. Did you wait a few seconds (say, 20) after deleting the Deployment Controller and before creating a new one? For me it sometimes takes some time before deletions propagate throughout the whole cluster and if I recreate too quickly, then the same resource is reused.

Concerning the heapster pod recreation you mentioned: pods have a [restartPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy). If set to `Never`, the pod will be recreated by its ReplicaSet in case it exits (this means a new pod resource is created and the old one is being deleted). My guess is that your heapster pod has this `Never` policy set. It might exit due to some error and reach a `Failed` state (you need to check that with the logs). Then after a short while the ReplicaSet creates a new pod.